# Why I only output a stack of a half size? c++

Tags: c++, stack, output

I am trying to output a stack from top to bottom, which is pretty easy. However, after I run the code below.

```cpp
stack<int> myS;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    myS.push(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < myS.size(); i++)
{
    cout << myS.top();
    myS.pop();
}
```

The output is `'111'` instead of `'111111'`. Although I have found the correct way to output it, I am still pretty confused about where my mistake is.

Comment: Why have you got `myS.pop()` - what do you think this line is doing?

Comment: Is this your own stack class or [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

Comment: With each call to pop() the size of the stack is decreased by one. So after 3 iterations i is 3 and myS.size() is also 3 and the loop terminates

Answer (score 3):

When you call `pop()`, the top element is removed, moving the other elements up a slot, and the `size()` is decremented. So, the 2nd element is now the 1st element, the 3rd element is now the 2nd element, and so on. Then you increment `i` so it refers *past* the newly moved top element to the *next* element. Because of these, your loop stops when it reaches the half-way point in the stack.

Let's unroll your `pop` loop to see what it actually does:

```cpp
// size=6
i = 0;
cout << myS.top(); // print 1
myS.pop(); // size=5
i++; //i=1
cout << myS.top(); // print 1
myS.pop(); // size=4
i++; // i=2
cout << myS.top(); // print 1
myS.pop(); // size=3
i++; // i=3
// i == size(), STOP
```

That is why you see only 3 `1`s printed.

To solve this, you can loop backwards instead:

```cpp
for(int i = myS.size(); i > 0; --i)
{
    cout << myS.top();
    myS.pop();
}
```

Or use a `while` loop instead:

```
while (myS.size() > 0) // or: while (!myS.empty())
{
    cout << myS.top();
    myS.pop();
}
```